# Query takes long time with php eloquent and sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I am facing some problems using `SQL Server` with `PHP`, I have this query in my code.

```
  Api::$eloquent->connection('cis')->select("
    SELECT
        SUM (DET.Peso_Salida) AS total,
      CLI.[Codigo Grupo] AS grupo
    FROM
        BNF2.SECO_DEVOLUCION_DETALLE AS DET
    INNER JOIN BNF2.SECO_DEVOLUCION_MAESTRO AS MAS ON DET.Correlativo_Maestro = MAS.Correlativo_Maestro AND MAS.Codigo_Cosecha=:co1
    INNER JOIN BNF.DETALLES_GENERALES_PESOS_2 AS REC ON DET.Numero_Lote=REC.Numero_Lote AND REC.Codigo_Cosecha=:co2
    INNER JOIN BNF.V_CLIENTES_CON_GRUPO AS CLI ON REC.Codigo_Entidad_Cliente_Actual= CLI.Codigo
    GROUP BY CLI.[Codigo Grupo]  
    ", [':co1' => $this->cosecha, ':co2' => $this->cosecha]);
```

The query is taking 15s and the `SQL Server` is having 100% `CPU`, now if I remove the parameters in the code, query takes 103ms very fast, So I don't understand why parameters are slowing down the query

```
Api::$eloquent->connection('cis')->select("
SELECT
    SUM (DET.Peso_Salida) AS total,
  CLI.[Codigo Grupo] AS grupo
FROM
    BNF2.SECO_DEVOLUCION_DETALLE AS DET
INNER JOIN BNF2.SECO_DEVOLUCION_MAESTRO AS MAS ON DET.Correlativo_Maestro = MAS.Correlativo_Maestro AND MAS.Codigo_Cosecha=9
INNER JOIN BNF.DETALLES_GENERALES_PESOS_2 AS REC ON DET.Numero_Lote=REC.Numero_Lote AND REC.Codigo_Cosecha=9
INNER JOIN BNF.V_CLIENTES_CON_GRUPO AS CLI ON REC.Codigo_Entidad_Cliente_Actual= CLI.Codigo
GROUP BY CLI.[Codigo Grupo]
", []);
```

This run very well, any Idea?

Comment: Can't know the exact problem, but [here's a bunch of answers about SQL Server becoming slow when parameters were added to the query.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459425/sql-server-query-fast-with-literal-but-slow-with-variable)

Comment: Also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443362/3585500) where the solution was to `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` because once you add variable parameters SQL Server has to worry about nulls in joins.

Comment: Note: ANSI_NULLS OFF is deprecated and considered a bad practice  my partial solution was validate the parameter and cocat it  in the string of the query

Comment: @AguilesPerez brings a very important point here. The documentation explicitly stated using `ANSI_NULLS OFF` will generate an error in the future.

Comment: as a partial solution I use "SELECT ... WHERE Codigo_Cosecha=".$cosecha;  but $cosecha is validated before as int to prevent errors

Answer (score 0):

You should be using parameterised query or Store Procedure.

There can be several reason for slow performance of query.That only `Table info` (including data type and length) and `Query Plan` can only reveal.

Index being one of them.

Since your question is like `"when using variable then query is slow. Query perform ok with constant value"`

We discuss similar thing few days back.

[Variables make query performance worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924110/variables-make-query-performance-worse/51927073#51927073)